# Command on 'Parent' ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I'm creating a context menu in code behind with a submenu.  I want the top level menu item to act as a command when pressed, but when I add child menu items, the command behavior seems to be taken over by the expanding behavior.  How can I remedy this?

```
MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
item.Command = DoSomething;
item.Header = "Parent";

MenuItem subItem = new MenuItem();
subItem.Command = DoSomethingElse;
subItem.Header = "Child";

item.Items.Add(subItem);
ContextMenuItems.Add(item);
```

```xml
<Button>
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItems}" />
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>

<CommandBinding Command="{x:Static DoSomething}"
                Executed="DoSomethingExecuted"/>

<CommandBinding Command="{x:Static DoSomethingElse}"
                Executed="DoSomethingElseExecuted"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want the top level menu item to act as a command when pressed

You should not be doing this, ever.

(*It's a matter of guidelines, consistency and user-expectancies*)

Comment: I think he wants something like a split-button

Comment: @SLaks: That would be different of course as the visual representation communicates that this actually is a button and not just a menu.

Comment: I know; and I suspect that that's what he wants.